# libavcodec Removal/Upgrade

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I am trying to install the usb_cam node.  I am getting error messages related to libavcodec.  More specifically declaration of AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO and definition of AVPacket.  Examining my avcodec.h and avutil.h those are indeed not defined.  Examining the avcodec.h and avutil.h on ffmpeg.org, those are defined.

Thus my next logical step is remove the half finished libraries on my computer and install the real libraries.  However, I cannot do this without uninstalling ROS.  Does anyone have a work around for this?  Should I update my repos maybe?  Any thoughts would be great, I would rather not spend the day uninstalling ros then reinstalling it.

System: Ubuntu 10.04

tl;dr: Using the package manager to remove libavcodec forces ROS removal.  I need to upgrade libavcodec.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11826/libavcodec-removal/upgrade/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try forcing an upgrade of libavcodec or you can look for an older version of usb_cam which is lucid compatible.  Or you can try to patch usb_cam to use the old avcodec API.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0